# How to delete items repeated less than k in a list

Tags: python, list, counter

In a python list, I want to delete all elements repeated less than 'k'.
for example if k == 3 then if our list is:

```
l = [a,b,c,c,c,a,d,e,e,d,d]
```

then the output must be:

```
[c,c,c,d,d,d]
```

what is a fast way to do that (my data is large), any good pythonic suggestion?

this is what I coded but I don't think it is the fastest and most pythonic way:

```
from collections import Counter

l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'd']

counted = Counter(l)

temp = []
for i in counted:
    if counted[i] < 3:
        temp.append(i)

new_l = []
for i in l:
    if i not in temp:
        new_l.append(i)

print(new_l)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please give us your attempt, so that we can better help you out.

Comment: How large is large? 1k, 1M, 1B, 1T?

Comment: Hint: use a `Counter`

Comment: @JordanSinger I've tried using "counter" and the sort it and then find the elements less than 'k' and then...

Comment: @peymanmohsenikiasari Thank you, can you please update your post with your code?

Comment: @Graipher 1Gigabyte

Comment: @JordanSinger it is done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to construct a dictionary mapping values to counts. Then use a list comprehension to filter for counts larger than a specified value.

```
from collections import Counter

L = list('abcccadeedd')
c = Counter(L)
res = [x for x in L if c[x] >=3]

# ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter
count_dict = Counter(l)
[el for el in l if count_dict[el]>2]
```

Comment: That keeps on rebuilding the `Counter` every element, though.

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force option would be to get the number of occurrences per item, then filter that output. The `collections.Counter` object works nicely here:

```
l = [a,b,c,c,c,a,d,e,e,d,d]
c = Counter(l)

# Counter looks like {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 3...}

l = [item for item in l if c[item]>=3]
```

Under the hood, `Counter` acts as a dictionary, which you can build yourself like so:

```
c = {}
for item in l:
    # This will check if item is in the dictionary
    # if it is, add to current count, if it is not, start at 0
    # and add 1
    c[item] = c.get(item, 0) + 1

# And the rest of the syntax follows from here
l = [item for item in l if c[item]>=3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Any drawback with this option?

```
l = ['a','b','c','c','c','a','d','e','e','d','d']

res = [ e for e in l if l.count(e) >= 3]

#=> ['c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
```

Comment: it is not fast. it will count "c" 3 times.